# Calculating combinations of courses for scheduling students

Tags: ruby, algorithm, binary-search, schedule

I'm want to match high school students with classes. Students have a list of courses that they need to take:

```
student_1_requests = [:EEN41, :SDN11T, :HUN11, :PPN41, :AUN21T, :TYN21T, :ZJPHN, :ZLUNCH]
```

A candidate schedule is a hash whose value is an array of courses that are offered at the same time:

```
candidate_schedule = {
  a_band => [:EEN41, :HGN22, :PPN41],
  b_band => [:SDN11T, :HUN11, :EEN41],
  c_band => [:TYN21T, :SLN11],
  d_band => [:PPN41, :TYN21T],
  l_band => [:ZLUNCH],
  e_band => [:EEN41, :SDN11T, :HUN11, :PPN41],
  f_band => [:AUN21T, :TYN21T, :PPN41],
  g_band => [:ZJPHN, :GAN42]
}
```

The student needs to have a class every period/band of the day. So, to be viable, a minimum of one of the courses in each band must appear in the student_requests, and for every band of the day the student must be able to be placed in a different one of their requests.

I am testing students' requests against a candidate schedule to meet most students needs. I'm trying to answer:

1. Will this `candidate_schedule` allow the student to be scheduled for all of their requests? Put another way, is there at least one combination of courses that would allow them to have all 8 of their courses, one different course in each band?
2. In how many combinations/different ways can the student be placed into the candidate schedule while being scheduled for every course they requested, and what those combinations are, like this:

   ```
   student_schedule_options = {
     :option_1 => {a => :EEN41, b => :HUN11, c => :TYN21T, d => :PPN41, e => :SDN11T, f => :AUN21T, g => :ZJPHN},
     :option_2 => ...
   }
   ```
3. It would be even more intriguing if it was possible to see cases where 7 out of 8 requests could be satisfied, and have it report the band and course/s that could not be matched, which would lend itself to making changes to the candidate schedule to improve it.

Comment: So from each band, a student must attend at least one or can attend all courses from `candidate_schedule`? Also, are these bands prerequisite of another? for example: to take f_band student must finish c_band and to take b_band student must finish d_band?

Comment: a band is an array listing all the courses that meet, for example, during the first class of the day. 

Every student will need to have a class to attend in the first period, and each student requests the same number of courses as there are bands- therefore, the course_request array must map to the candidate_schedule such that a different one of each of the eight courses is available in each band of the day.

The course request array is for one student, the candidate_schedule is the courses available for the school. With an approach to this I would loop through all the students.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a brute-force method.

I'm not sure if your `candidate_schedule` variable is actually a hash, since the keys are not strings or symbols, but you really need just an array of arrays. If it's a hash, extract the values from the `candidate_schedule` hash:

```
>> schedule = candidate_schedule.values
=> [[:EEN41, :HGN22, :PPN41],
 [:SDN11T, :HUN11, :EEN41],
 [:TYN21T, :SLN11],
 [:PPN41, :TYN21T],
 [:ZLUNCH],
 [:EEN41, :SDN11T, :HUN11, :PPN41],
 [:AUN21T, :TYN21T, :PPN41],
 [:ZJPHN, :GAN42]]
```

Now, using Ruby's array methods, create a set of all possible permutations of the student's schedule, and select only those permutations for which all elements match one of the class schedule elements at the same index:

```
>> student_schedule_options = student_1_requests.permutation.select { |p| p.each_with_index.all? { |request, i| schedule[i].include?(request) } }
=> [[:EEN41, :SDN11T, :TYN21T, :PPN41, :ZLUNCH, :HUN11, :AUN21T, :ZJPHN],
 [:EEN41, :HUN11, :TYN21T, :PPN41, :ZLUNCH, :SDN11T, :AUN21T, :ZJPHN]]
```

If you are processing many schedules, you may want to explore more efficient matching algorithms, but this one is quick and dirty.

Comment: Thank you! I was struggling to envision how to do the brute forcing accounting for creating those combinations, looks like I was overcomplicating things. This is perfect for my purposes, but I definitely want to go off and explore matching algorithms- thank you!